# Where can I get all observers(events) of current page?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, debugging, debug, xdebug

Where in the code magento2 trigger one by one all events of observers. I want to debug it by xdebug and find all events that can be on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a break point in this file in the dispatch function:

vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php

Tt will be triggered by all observer. When an even is triggered Magento runs dispatch like this:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'catalog_category_prepare_save',
        ['category' => $category, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
);
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I need!